# Spyder Version 5 Standalone With Mini Conda Commands

Tags: package, command, conda

I am using Spyder version 5 the standalone version with Miniconda.

I was hoping someone could shed some light on the following questions:-

1. I know how to update all the packages within a given environment, however does anyone know what the command is to update a specific package within a given environment and how to delete a specific package within a given environment?
2. Does anyone know what the command is to upgrade Python from say 2.7 to 2.8 using Spyder standalone within mini conda.
3. When I remove an environment I get the following message in mini conda:-
   "Remove all packages in environment C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\minicdm:" - Whats all this about???
4. And finally I am trying to create a list of common commands for newbies like myself and I was wondering if anyone could add anything to the list I currently have:-

4.1 conda env list                  -   List all environments and places an asterisk to which environment is active.

4.2 conda deactivate             -   Deactivates active environment, you may or may not need to be in the folder to deactivate it

4.3 conda env remove -n          -   Removes the environment, must be deactivated before it can be removed.

4.4 conda update -n  --all           -   Updates all the packages within a given environment.

4.5 conda create -n  -y          -   Creates a conda environment

4.6 conda activate               -   Activates a conda environment

4.7 conda install spyder-kernels scikit-learn -y    -   Installs a package in the activate environment

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Do not rely on third-party information. Read the the docs:
https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/index.html